# Angular 2 work on with html tags that are in app template?

Tags: angular

I dont have a SPA. I have a html page (index.html) that want to host some angular2 component or may by directive to work with html tags in `index.html`.
The `index.html` is just for initialing th angular2 app?!
Please look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/TpsBwe?p=preview for clarify what i want to do.
In Angular 1 i can attach the angular controllers to any tags in the index.html and use the scope of the controller within the tag.
Thank a lot for any advises.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular2 everything has to be within a root component. You can use `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the template of your root component to transclude child elements of your root component, but as far as I know this is limited on the root component.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.  Everything you want Angular to touch will need to be inside the main application tag.

But you can nest things well, so this would be possible:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'sub-page',
    directives: [Navbar],
    pipes: [],
    providers: [],
    template: `
<br>
<br>
<div><button (click) = "onSave()">I'm back in the app</button></div>
`
})
export class SubPage {
    constructor() {}

    subPage() {
        alert("I'm here");
    }
}
```

Then you would add it to your main component:

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {MyClickDirective,MyClickDirective2,SubPage} from './mydirectives'

// Alerter fn: monkey patch during test
export function alerter(msg?: string) {
    window.alert(msg);
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
     <button (click) = "onSave()">Save.Work</button>
    </div>
    <sub-page></subpage>
  `,
  directives: [MyClickDirective,MyClickDirective2,SubPage]
})
export class App {
    alert = alerter;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
    onSave(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let evtMsg = event ? ' Event target is ' + (<HTMLElement>event.target).innerText : '';
        this.alert('Saved.' + evtMsg)
    }
}
```

Note that I'm including the newly defined `SubPage` class in directives and using the `<sub-page></sub-page>` tag in the template.

That would give you the same layout, just by nesting components.